# Inscribe circle in equilateral triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm trying to inscribe equilateral triangle. What am I doing wrong.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
        \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B)
        \tkzGetPoint{C}
        \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
        \tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rIN}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzDrawCircle[R,blue](O,\rIN pt)
        \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrongly inscribed circle]

Comment: There was a bug to determine the bisector of a 60 degree angle. This is corrected in version 4 which is coming soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect some kind of bug when inscribing a circle into an equilateral triangle. It works perfectly with many other triangles, but  when you approach too near 60°, it fails to do it. For example, with an angle of 59.9°:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
       
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (59.9:4);

        \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
        
        \tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rIN}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzDrawCircle[R,blue](O,\rIN pt)
        \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
              
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: angle=59.9]

But with an angle of 59.99°, it fails:

[image: angle=59.99]

So you're not doing anything wrong. If you want to draw it anyway with `tkz-euclide`, you can do it "by hand":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
       
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (60:4);

        \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=1,C=1) \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzInterLL(A,O)(C,B) \tkzGetPoint{A'}
        \tkzDrawCircle[color=blue](O,A')
        
        
       \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,O)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
              
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a plain TikZ way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2} % radius of circumcircle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\R/2} % radius of incircle
\path
(90:\R) coordinate (A) node[above]{$A$}
(210:\R) coordinate (B) node[below left]{$B$}
(-30:\R) coordinate (C) node[below right]{$C$};
\fill[red] (0,0) circle(1.5pt);
\draw[red] (0,0) circle(\r);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `tangent` approach.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=180]
    \tkzDefPoint(0, 0){CircleCenter}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R,very thick](CircleCenter,3cm)

    % Define 3 points on circle. Angles for equilateral triangle
    
    \tkzDefPoint( 90:3){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(210:3){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(330:3){B}
    

    % Tangents
    \tkzDefLine[perpendicular=through C](CircleCenter,C)\tkzGetPoint{C2}
    \tkzDefLine[perpendicular=through A](CircleCenter,A)\tkzGetPoint{A2}
    \tkzDefLine[perpendicular=through B](CircleCenter,B)\tkzGetPoint{B2}
   

    % Find the points by intersecting the tangents
    \tkzInterLL(C,C2)(A,A2)\tkzGetPoint{CC}
    \tkzInterLL(A,A2)(B,B2)\tkzGetPoint{AA}
    \tkzInterLL(B,B2)(C,C2)\tkzGetPoint{BB}
    
    % Draw triangle
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](AA,BB,CC)

    % Draw points
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=3pt](CircleCenter)
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=3pt](AA,BB,CC)
    \node at (CircleCenter)[below right]{O};
    \node at (BB)[left]{B};
    \node at (CC)[right]{C};
    \node at (AA)[above]{A};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}
[image]